# link to mysql single record from search with pagination

Tags: php, ajax, pagination

I am trying to link through to the single row record information in my mysql database from my search using php/ajax_pagination and the code that I am trying to get to work is:

```
<div id="posts_content">
<?php
//Include pagination class file
include('Pagination.php');

//Include database configuration file
include('dbConfig.php');

$limit = 3;

//get number of rows
$queryNum = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as postNum FROM posts");
$resultNum = $queryNum->fetch_assoc();
$rowCount = $resultNum['postNum'];

//initialize pagination class
$pagConfig = array(
    'totalRows' => $rowCount,
    'perPage' => $limit,
    'link_func' => 'searchFilter'
);
$pagination =  new Pagination($pagConfig);

//get rows
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $limit");

if($query->num_rows > 0){ ?>
    <div class="posts_list">
    <?php
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){ 
            $postID = $row['id'];
    ?>
        <div class="list_item"><a href="file.php?id="'.$row['id'].'"><h2><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></h2></a></div>
    <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $pagination->createLinks(); ?>
<?php } ?>
</div>
```

There is obviously something wrong with my href link:

```
<a href="file.php?id="'.$row['id'].'"><h2><?php echo    $row["title"]; ?></h2></a>
```

OR my file.php page:

```
  <?php 


 // GET ID FROM THE URL
 $id = $_GET['id'];

  ?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Ajax Pagination with Search and Filter in PHP</title>
 <link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>


<?php 

$sql =mysql_query("select * from posts where id='".$id."'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
?>
    <tr>
        <th>title:</th>
        <th>created:</th>
        <th>modified:</th>
        <th>statusr:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row['title']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['created']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['modified']?></td>
        <td><?=$row['status']?></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    }
?>
```

But I cannot understand why as everything else seems to be working fine, maybe I have been looking at this to long and missed something blatently obvious... but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Enclose `$row['id']` in `<?php ?>` tags

Comment: Of course! Thanks I should of noticed unfortunatley that still isnt working and my url is being cut off at the php tag

         `<div class="list_item"><a href="file.php?id="<?php $row['id'] ?>"><h2><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></h2></a></div>`

Comment: You forgot `echo`. Note you might be able to use "short tags" `<?= $row['id'] ?>`, if your environment is configured to support them. (it's a php config setting)

Comment: I eventually got this link to work:  `<div class="list_item"><a href="file.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><h2><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></h2></a></div>`  But my file.php isnt showing any content? I have updated my latest file.php code above thankyou for any more help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use Below Code:

```
<div class="list_item"><a href="file.php?id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><h2><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></h2></a></div>
```

Comment: I eventually got this link to work:

`<div class="list_item"><a href="file.php?id=<?php echo $row['id'] ?>"><h2><?php echo $row["title"]; ?></h2></a></div>`

But my file.php isnt showing any content? I have updated my latest file.php code above thankyou for any more help.

Comment: Thanks again for you help!

Comment: If you find my answer helpfull please consider accepting as correct answer TY